# C# .NET MAUI keyboard becoming visible doesn't resize page contents properly ( Android )

Tags: c#, keyboard, resize, maui

When the editor is selected, the layout does not resize properly when the keyboard appears.  Anyone know how to fix?  Resize worked properly when target framework was .NET 6 but not .NET 7 or 8.

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ( )
    {
        InitializeComponent ( );

        BoxView box = new BoxView { Color = Colors.LightBlue } ;
        ContentView view = new ContentView { BackgroundColor = Colors.Yellow } ;
        Editor editor = new Editor { BackgroundColor = Colors.Green } ;

        Grid grid = new Grid ( ) ;

        grid.AddColumnDefinition ( new ColumnDefinition ( ) );

        grid.AddRowDefinition ( new RowDefinition { Height = 100 } );
        grid.AddRowDefinition ( new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength ( 1 , GridUnitType.Star ) } );
        grid.AddRowDefinition ( new RowDefinition { Height = 100 } );

        grid.Add ( box , 0 , 0 );
        grid.Add ( view , 0 , 1 );
        grid.Add ( editor , 0 , 2 );

        MainPage = new ContentPage { Content = grid };
    }
}
```

[image: example]

Comment: Please show what it looks like to understand the problem you're facing. And on which platform does this occur?

Comment: @Julian Hi, please take a look at this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn1AK.png.  Happens in the emulator and on my phone.  It was fine using .NET 6

Comment: @Julian The expected/desired behavior is for the yellow content view to shrink and the top box and editor be fully visible... Is there another/proper way to add an editor at the bottom of the screen??

Comment: @Julian Using Android, untested on iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust Soft Keyboard Input Mode on Android.

Please add the following code to `App.xaml`

```
<Application ...
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:Application.WindowSoftInputModeAdjust="Resize">
  ...
</Application>
```

For more information, check document: [Soft Keyboard Input Mode on Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode) .

Comment: Does not work on MAUI

Comment: I tested on my android emulator(Pixel 5-Android 33), the top box and editor could be fully visible.  What device did you test on, and can you share a screenshot of your result?

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me on Android ( untested on other platforms ):

Open the `Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs` file and add `Window.SetSoftInputMode ( SoftInput.AdjustResize );` like so...

```cs
protected override void OnCreate ( Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
  base.OnCreate ( savedInstanceState );

  Window.SetSoftInputMode ( SoftInput.AdjustResize );
}
```